# UIButton in Subview calling properties

Tags: ios5

It's a little bit to explain why I'd like to implement this design.

But the question I want to ask is : **If I have a view and it's controller is ControllerA, and now I want to add a subview in my that view suppose View1. And that subview View1 contains a button, which I set the IBAction point to the ControllerA.**

But I found that this View1 button cannot change some properties in original view's object like `UIImageview.hidden`.

Can't a button in subview alter things inside superview ? Or I need to set up other things to finish this task.

Comment: **This is not related to Xcode** (unless you're trying to add subviews to Xcode's view hierarchy itself, which I doubt).

Comment: I only select ios5 at first, i don't know why others show......

Comment: @user1713790 Have you actually confirmed that when you have you button on the subview that you've correctly linked it to the IBAction? If you're calling the same IBAction in ControllerA, it's inconceivable that it's getting called in both cases, but working in one, but not the other. It makes no sense. So please confirm (a) that the IBAction is being called in both cases; (b) if the problem persists, describe a little about your code (separate UIView classes? or everything in the same view controller? etc.). Perhaps show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to understand exactly what you're saying but it sounds like you're trying to access a subview of a UIView instance outside of that UIView. If it is not a UIView subclass where you have an ivar/property reference to that subview, you can try giving it a tag and accessing it that way.

example:

```
UIView *topLevelView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *viewA = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *otherView = [[UIView alloc] init];
otherView.tag = 5;
[topLevelView addSubview:viewA];
[topLevelView addSubview:otherView];


UIView *viewASubview = [[UIView alloc] init];
[viewA addSubview:viewASubview];


UIView *referenceToOtherView = [viewASubview.superview.superview viewWithTag:5];
UIView *anotherReferenceToOtherView = [topLevelView viewWithTag:5];
```

Comment: I want to add use a button inside a subview A to change the property of a button inside A's superview. And Both view is under the same controller

Comment: The answer I gave you explains how to do that using tags. The fact that it is a button is trivial because it's just a view. Hook up an IBAction to perform this. You just need to use`superview`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you were try to add a `button` inside the `UIView` which is also a `subview` of `View(UIViewController`).

as you told whenever you try to access your Button property then you could not do same.

this is happening because whenevre we create anything through the XIb if we want access that UIControl or whatever  then we have make Reference of that in Our Source Code.so you'll have hook up the UIButton with reference from the Xcode.
As i am doing in below Image.

[image: Try in this Way]

I hope i got your Point. it'll be helpful to you

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but this is not my case. I want to use a button  in a subview A to change property of button B in A's superview. If I use other button C inside A's superview to change property of button, it works; however, the button inside subview A just can't work